# TensorFlow - optimization with normalization constraints

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any implementation using TensorFlow to optimize a vector under a constraint such as |w|^2==1 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a soft constraint to your loss: `some_constant * (norm(w)- 1)^2` but, as far as I know, there are no functionalities specifically for constrained optimization.

Comment: I see. Thank you for suggestion. I will try it.